# create matrix based on another matrix contain index of element with na value

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, lapply, sapply

> I have a matrix that contains indices of column ides to the element of matrix I want create it

```
>  index
         [,1] [,2] [,3] 
    [1,]    1    NA   3    
    [2,]    1    2    NA    
    [3,]    1    3    NA    
    [4,]    1    3    5    
    [5,]    1    4    5    
    [6,]    2    NA   NA    
    [7,]    3    4    NA
```

example first row have the column id 1 ,NA , 3 that set to it value 1 and ignore NA

second row have the column id 1 , 2 , NA that set to it value 1

now I want to create the following matrix:

```
     a1 a2 a3  a4 a5
[1,]  1  0  1  0  0
[2,]  1  1  0  0  0
[3,]  1  0  1  0  0
[4,]  1  0  1  0  1
[5,]  1  0  0  1  1  
[6,]  0  1  0  0  0
[7,]  0  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create a matrix with 0's where number of rows is same as `index` and number of columns is the maximum value in `index`. We could then create a row, column matrix using `row` function as row index and `index` values as column index and turn them to 1.

```
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = max(index, na.rm = TRUE), nrow = nrow(index))
mat[cbind(c(row(index)), c(index))] <- 1
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    1    0    1
#[5,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[6,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    1    1    0
```

**data**

```
index <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, NA, 2, 3, 3, 4, NA, 4, 3, NA, 
         NA, 5, 5, NA, NA), .Dim = c(7L, 3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `rep` to create the row index

```
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = max(index, na.rm = TRUE), nrow = nrow(index))
mat[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(index)), ncol(index)), c(index))] <- 1
```

#### data

```
index <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, NA, 2, 3, 3, 4, NA, 4, 3, NA, 
     NA, 5, 5, NA, NA), .Dim = c(7L, 3L))
```